# Using apply functions instead of for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have the following data:

```
dataframe = A
1    2    3    4    5

0    1    0    0    0
1    0    0    0    0
0    0    0    1    0
```

I would like to calculate `sum(colnum * value(column))` for every row.

My code:

```
num <- apply(A, 1, function(x){
  sum <- 1 * x[1] + 2 * x[2] + 3 * x[3] + 4 * x[4] + 5 * x[5]
  return(sum)
})
```

Or it could be implemented using a `for` loop as:

```
num <- apply(A, 1, function(x){
  sum <- 0
  for (i in 1:5){
    sum = sum + (i * x[i])
  }
  return(sum)
})
```

Is there a better way of implementing the above without using `for` loop or writing the whole code myself.

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of ways yo vectorize this. Such as `colSums(t(A) * 1:5)` or ```rowSums(sweep(A, 2, 1:5, `*`))``` and about a dozen of others.

Comment: `rowSums(col(A)*A)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks. Both solutions work perfectly.

Comment: @docendodiscimus post as an answer please.